# Calculating synchronous orbits

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to make an equation to calculate the synchronous orbit of a planet. I found an equation on a wiki and tried to copy that in C#, but the result is completely incorrect.

**Equation:**
[image: KSP equation]

> **a** is the altitude from the planet
>   **G** is the gravitational constant 6.674E-11
>   **M** is the mass of the planet
>   **t** is the orbital period (in sec)
>   **Rp** is the radius of the planet

**Code:**

```
double G = 6.674E-11;
syncOrbit = Math.Pow((G * b.Mass * Math.Pow(b.orbit.period, 2.0)) / (4 * Math.Pow(Math.PI, 2.0)), 1.0 / 3.0) - b.Radius;
```

**Inputs:**

- b.Mass = 5.29157926281091E+22 kg
- b.orbit.period = 9203545 s
- b.Radius = 600000 m

**Wanted result:** 2868.74 km

**Given result:** 195814.71 km

Did I do something wrong in the code or do I just have an incorrect equation (from the wiki)?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `Math.Sqrt` in your implementation....

Comment: extra? I need that for the square root, or do I?

Comment: `Math.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)` is doing the cube-root already.

Comment: It is still giving me the wrong result

Comment: Can you give an example of your inputs and what you expected as output?

Comment: Moved the inputs and expected result into the OP

Comment: why do you expect the answer to be 2868.74 km? I've gotten the same thing as you with both a calculator and a program.

Comment: The equation you have is [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law) with an adjustment for the planet's radius.

Comment: which planet are you computing this for? your numbers don't seem correct for the earth. also, according to the above link, `M` is the mass of the star and `m` is the mass of the planet (which are summed together), with `m` often being ignored since it's relatively insignificant compared to the mass of the star.

Comment: (ok I guess it's better to say that `M` is the mass of the thing being orbited, and `m` is the mass of the thing orbiting.)

Comment: I found my mistake, I was using the wrong orbital period. I used the time of one orbit around the sun (1 year), while I needed the siderial rotation period of the planet (1 day) to get the correct result.

Comment: What does "synchronous" mean in this context? A satellite orbit can be sun synchronous for instance, but a planet's orbit?

Comment: A synchronous orbit is an orbit where the orbital period equals the rotation rate of the orbited body. A little bit the same as a stationary orbit but without the inclination and eccentricity restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, I was using the wrong orbital period. I used the time of one orbit around the sun (1 year), while I needed the siderial rotation period of the planet (1 day) to get the correct result.

```
double G = 6.674E-11;
syncOrbit = Math.Pow((G * b.Mass * Math.Pow(b.rotationPeriod, 2.0)) / (4 * Math.Pow(Math.PI, 2.0)), 1.0 / 3.0) - b.Radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double inner = G * b.Mass * Math.Pow(b.orbit.period, 2.0)/ ( 4* Math.PI * Math.PI);
double answer = Math.Pow(inner, 1.0/3.0) - b.Radius;
```

Comment: @ArnePeirs how do you get the expected result? Get a calculator and enter those values you'll get what the program returns

Answer (score 0):

So my guess is that you misunderstand the equation. I'm not a physicist, but the formula seems to be for calculating the average distance between two orbiting objects. Using the formula and refactoring your code into a program, I get the following, which generates a correct answer using values for the Sun and Earth.

```
const double G = 6.674E-11;
Console.WriteLine("G is {0}", G);

const double massOfEarth = 5.972E+24;
const double massOfSun = 1.989E+30;
const double mass = massOfSun + massOfEarth;
Console.WriteLine("mass is {0}", mass);

// 365 days in seconds
const double period = 3.15569E+7;
Console.WriteLine("period is {0}", period);

// radius of the earth
const double radius = 6.371E+6;
Console.WriteLine("radius is {0}", radius);

double denominator = 4 * Math.Pow(Math.PI, 2.0);
Console.WriteLine("Denominator is {0}", denominator);

double numerator = G * mass * Math.Pow(period, 2.0);
Console.WriteLine("numerator is {0}", numerator);

double fraction = numerator / denominator;
Console.WriteLine("fraction is {0}", fraction);

double root = Math.Pow(fraction, 1.0 / 3.0);
Console.WriteLine("root is {0}", root);

double result = root - radius;
Console.WriteLine("final result is {0}", result);
```

Output is:

```
G is 6.674E-11
mass is 1.989005972E+30
period is 31556900
radius is 6371000
Denominator is 39.4784176043574
numerator is 1.32193760361067E+35
fraction is 3.34850706747872E+33
root is 149606480630.306
final result is 149600109630.306
```

Where the average distance between the Sun and Earth is 149.6 billion meters.